# Biplots for Functional Principal Component Scores

Tags: r, pca, biplot

I'm trying to get the biplots between two F. principal components (or harmonics). I provide an example from `fda` package doc. to solve the riddle:

```
library(fda)
#BASIS FUNCTIONS
daybasis65 <- create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), nbasis=65, period=365)
#DATA
harmaccelLfd <- vec2Lfd(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0), c(0, 365))
#SMOOTHING BASIS TO THE DATA
harmfdPar <- fdPar(daybasis65, harmaccelLfd, lambda=1e5)
daytempfd <- smooth.basis(day.5, CanadianWeather$dailyAv[,,"Temperature.C"],
daybasis65, fdnames=list("Day", "Station", "Deg C"))$fd
#FPCA
daytemppcaobj <- pca.fd(daytempfd, nharm=4, harmfdPar)
#RETRIEVING COMPONENTS
f_loadings <- daytemppcaobj $harmonics
#BIPLOT BETWEEN 1ST AND 2ND HARMONIC
biplot(f_loadings[1],f_loadings[2])
+Error in 1L:n : argument of length 0
```

Please take into account that `f_loadings` and `daytempfd` are `fd` objects while `daytemppcaobj` is a `pca.fd` object.

Thank you in advance. All type of help is welcome and rewarded!

Please if you have any idea to implement this with `ggplot2`, please, don't hesitate to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case `biplot` is not the right function as it does not admit `fd` and `pcafd objects`. FDA package has `plotscores` which allows to BIplot Principal Component Scores or in other words,  draw the scores of the curves on pairs of principal components

```
plotscores(daytemppcaobj, scores=c(1, 2))
```

[image]